# First Touching During A Field Goal

Tags: american-football

Ok, Team 1 tries a field goal at 30 yards, this is failed but it goes on 10 yards where, before it lands, is illegaly touched by a kicking team player (First touching), so in this case is the ball immediately dead or can a receiving team player recover and advace it? And if none of the receiving team recovers it, where will the ball be placed after? At the spot of the kick or where is touched by kicking team?